# "Table 1.1" results in table caption being slightly off-centered

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, captions

I want my table as well as table caption to be perfectly centered. However, using justification=centering results in the caption itself being centered, but then shifted right due to the "Table 1.1" being added to the left. How can I fix this?

[image]

```
\begin{table}[ht]
\centering
\scalebox{0.7}{
\begin{tabular}{l}
\midrule
4 energy related LLD \\
\midrule
sum of auditory spectrum (loudness) \\
sum of RASTA-style filtered auditory spectrum \\
RMS energy \\
zero-crossing rate \\
\midrule
54 spectral LLD \\
\midrule
RASTA-style auditory spectrum, bands 1–26 (0–8 kHz) \\
MFCC 1–14 \\
spectral energy 250–650 Hz, 1 k–4 kHz \\
spectral roll off point 0.25, 0.50, 0.75, 0.90 \\
spectral flux, entropy, variance, skewness, kurtosis, \\
slope, psycho-acoustic sharpness, harmonicity \\
\midrule
6 voicing related LLD \\
\midrule
F0 by SHS + Viterbi smoothing, probability of voicing \\
logarithmic HNR, jitter (local, delta), shimmer (local) \\
\midrule
\end{tabular}
}
\captionsetup{justification=centering}
\caption{Baseline feature set of the INTERSPEECH 2012 Speaker Trait Challenge as shown in \cite{SurveySpeakerTraits}}
\label{table:InterspeechFeatureSet}
\end{table}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Add `\captionsetup{format=plain}`. The default is `hang`. This being said, you shouldn't scale a table contents – it leads to inconsistent font sizes.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this solved my issue perfectly! :)